# Who are the Missing Members of this Noble Family?

Tags: knowledge, pattern, number-sequence, no-computers

Could you please find the Missing Nobles?

$118$, $?$, $54$, $?$, $18$, $10$, $?$

Comment: Is [tag:no-computers] required?

Comment: Probably not..in lot of earlie puzzles, computers were used where they were not required..so  I was using it to point out that they are not needed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are

> 86, 36, 2

Explanation:

> Noble gases atomic number in periodic table, in decreasing order

Comment: Quick work!......

Comment: thanks... it is not that hard for krypton to find krypton... :)

Comment: Good one,,I will warn Superman to be wary of you.

Comment: Is there any reason that 18 is excluded?

Comment: Thx..it was an oversight..forgive me Argon..when I took it from my puzzle notebook..it didn’t make it to puzzle..I will edit and add now..thx again for catching it.

Comment: @AdmiralJota sorry i didn't noticed that too!